# JPA N+1 issue with inheritance

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

If I am in the situation where I have a n+1 problem I normally use the JPA "join fetch" keyword if it is only one indirection (i. e. select p from Person p join fetch p.address) or if it is more than one indirection I use a JPA provider-proprietary query hint, which is in my case eclipselink (i. e. select p from person with the query hint eclipselink.join-fetch=p.address.city). Thats well explained in the article [Java Persistence Performance](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.de/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html).

Anyway, lately I stumbled over a datamodel where two entities where subclassed by another one.
I have an `Account` which owns a `Contact`. A Contact itself is a abstract superclass which is extended by a `Person` or a `Company`. And a Person does have a relationship to a list of `Hobby`ies.

```
@Entity
public class Account
{
    @OneToOne
    private Contact contact;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Contact {}
```

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Contact
{
    @OneToMany
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Contact {}
```

I need to load a list of Accounts, `select a from Account a`. I surely ran into the n+1 problem, because of the hobbies. No problem I thought, with the two above mentioned and well probed solutions I can cope with the n+1 problem. But soon I realized that does not work.

`select a from Account a join fetch a.contacts` does not fetch the hobbies. Nor does `select a from Account a` with the query hint `eclipselink.join-fetch=a.contacts`. And `select a from Account a` with the query hint `eclipselink.join-fetch=a.contacts.hobbies` throws a
`... navigated to a non-existent relationship`-Exception.

I also tried to use the JPA treat-function i. e. `select a from Account a join fetch treat(a.contact as Person) p join fetch p.hobbies`, but that does not fetch the hobbies and only fetches the Persons and not the Companies along.

Does anyone have an idea how to use join fetch or eclipselink query hints to accomplish such a query optimization?

---

**EDIT**

In order to answer the comment by Chris.
The `@BatchFetch` annotation at the hobbies does not have any impact on the query. There is no difference to the queries without it.

Here are the sqls generated by each query with the @BatchFetch annotation

`select a from Account a`

```
1 SELECT id, contact_id FROM account
2 SELECT DISTINCT DTYPE FROM contact WHERE (ID = ?)
3 SELECT t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t1.ID, t1.FOUNDED FROM contact t0, company t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID) AND t0.DTYPE = ?))
4 SELECT DISTINCT DTYPE FROM contact WHERE (ID = ?)
5 SELECT t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t1.ID, t1.NAME FROM contact t0, person t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?)))
6 SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
... (repetition of lines 2 to 6)
```

`select a from Account a join fetch a.contacts`

```
SELECT t3.ID, t3.contact_id, t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t1.NAME, t2.ID, t2.FOUNDED FROM contacts t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN person t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN company t2 ON (t2.ID = t0.ID), account t3 WHERE (t0.ID = t3.contact_id)
SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
SELECT ID, OUTDOOR, PERSON_ID FROM hobby WHERE (PERSON_ID = ?)
...
```

Comment: Join fetch might not be the best option for a 1:m. Is there any reason not to just specify batch fetching this relationship with the @BatchFetch annotation? https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm

Comment: Hi @Chris, you are right, I might use `@BatchFetch` over `@JoinFetch` for better performance. But the problem is the same. If I use `eclipselink.batch` query hint I cannot define the relationship. I also tried to use the `@BatchFetch` annotation in the `Person` and `Account` class, but it made no difference in the generated SQL statements. Meanwhile I do belive that it is not possible to optimize the queries in such a datamodel :-(

Comment: In the case of using 'treat', how are you verifying that hobbies aren't being fetched? I find it strange it would accept the JPQL if it wasn't processing it -show the SQL that is generated. Treat forces all other subclasses to be excluded, which is why you cannot get Company instances included - a join from company to Hobby doesn't make sense in your model and so needs to be excluded.  What is the SQl being issues when you put the @BatchFetch on the hobbies relationship and not within the query?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I've edited the question in oder to show the sql generated. @Chris your are right about `treat`. It is no solution because it only fetches the persons and not the companies. I still think that it is not possible to do what I want :-(

Comment: You have thrown together some different options that do not mesh and do not do what you think they do.  First, JPA does not allow nested fetch joins, so that is why any query with " a join fetch a.contact p join fetch p.hobbies" would fail, even without the inheritance issue.  Second, batch fetching by default uses the original query for filtering - something difficult to do when inheritance is involved.  Have you tried the other BatchFetchType options such as IN or even EXISTS?